# Google Scripts documentation for Historical Stock Info?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a google spreadsheet right now. The goal is for it to automatically get a stock open, close and change for a date in the past.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the documentation and it doesn't seem to be working out.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/historical-stock-info) is the link to the class I have to use, but I don't know how to implement it.

Here is the code I have now for current stock data, that works. I spent a long time with the documentation and piecing together bits of code that I found.

```
function stockRun() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var row = 2;
 while (true) {
 if (!sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue()) {
 var ticker = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
 if (!ticker) break; 
 var stockInfo = FinanceApp.getStockInfo(ticker);
 sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(stockInfo.closeyest);
sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(stockInfo.priceopen);
sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(stockInfo.change);
sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(stockInfo.changepct + "%");
 } 
row++;    
}
}
```

Now that I want historical data, I'm not really sure where to go. I don't understand how I can use the class [StockInfoSnapshot[]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/stock-info-snapshot) and use the properties of it.

Thanks so much for all your help! I know this must seem so simple, but it's really confusing to me. Once I understand how to use the class I'll be able to work on it and expand my program from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that all class available before are now in a "Deprecated" mode !! :
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/finance-app?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/stock-info?hl=en

Deprecation of Finance service

We’re excited to bring you these new tools. With these new additions, we have also deprecated Finance service. It will remain available for the next six months but will be turned off on September 26, 2014.
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.fr/2014/02/more-apps-script-apis-and-features.html

see also : http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3715